# Unable to install rjava in macbook pro 64-bit

Tags: java, r, macos

I am trying to run the JDBC package. however, that requires that I install the rjava package. when i install rjava library, i get the following error:

```
library(rJava)
Unable to find any JVMs matching version "(null)".
No Java runtime present, try --request to install.

Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘rJava’:
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
  call: dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...)
  error: unable to load shared object '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so':
  dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so, 6): Library not loaded: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/server/libjvm.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so
  Reason: image not found
In addition: Warning message:
In system("/usr/libexec/java_home", intern = TRUE) :
  running command '/usr/libexec/java_home' had status 1
```

Comment: Do you have a JDK installed? Other things to try: `R CMD javareconf`, building rJava from source instead of using a binary, setting a `JAVA_HOME` environment variable